# Spring Security OAuth2 Login using password Grant

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1 for a spring boot mvc application. I also have an OAuth2 Authorization server that is already setup and configured separately.

I'm attempting to utilize Spring Security 5.2 OAuth to process the user login using Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

My goal is to have users authenticate with the OAuth2 server, retrieve their UserDetails from the JWT that is returned, then retrieve some additional user information from my application's database in the LoginSuccessHandler. I want to use the password grant because it will give me a JWT with a TRUSTED_CLIENT authority which will allow my requests to do more privileged actions when working with other services and still maintain the Resource Owner on the requests.

So far I have the following code:

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          thecompany:
            authorization-uri: https://thecompany.com/authentication/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://thecompany.com/authentication/oauth/token
        registration:
          myapplication:
            provider: thecompany
            client-name: My Application
            client-id: my_app
            client-secret: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: password
```

WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
               /* some url filters */
                
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .loginPage("/mypage/login/")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/mypage/logon/")
                        .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .failureUrl("/mypage/login/")
                ).oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout/")
                .addLogoutHandler(new HeaderWriterLogoutHandler(new ClearSiteDataHeaderWriter(CACHE)))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new MyAppLogoutSucessHandler())
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout");
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I attempt to login, it successfully sends the request to

> /oauth2/authorization/myapplication

but I get the following Exception:

```
2020-06-26 11:01:03.953 ERROR 51280 --- [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-9009-exec-6] OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter : Authorization Request failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Authorization Grant Type (password) for Client Registration with Id: myapplication

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Authorization Grant Type (password) for Client Registration with Id: myapplication
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Can someone please help me to figure out what the correct configuration would be for my application?

Comment: Is this exception from oauth server? You should provide your ouath server configuration

Comment: This is all from the client application side. The OAuth Server is working correctly, we've integrated the server with a number of applications already, some using password grant, successfully

Comment: Rambo Commando Did you managed to solve an issue? I have a same one..

Comment: @Mgreg No, the grant type was not supported at the time we were using this library. We ended up using Keycloak